# How to address bad research experience

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, research-undergraduate

I want to apply to CS PhD programs this year. Just a litte background: I did my BS and (non thesis) MS in EE/ECE at the same school. During my BS I did two semesters of undergrad research that went fine and gave me valuable experience.

During the second (last) semester of my MS I took on for-credit research with a professor. We got all the forms settled and decided on a project. However, after a certain point (me reading papers to catch up on the work) he stopped responding completely. I sent him emails frequently asking for resources to start my project (required some simulation resources at the least), but he never responded. I also tried to catch him at his office whenever I was free during the semester but completely failed. At the end of the semester I was awarded a B. Should I even address this on my application? Would it look bad to not include this experience at all?

The other weird caveat is that this is the only B throughout both of my degrees, so it is pretty noticeable.

Comment: Can you explore with the department office why he might have dropped out on you? That might be valuable to know.

Comment: I might be able to, but they wont know anything. He never officially dropped out. He just completely ignored everything about my project until the end of the semester when he gave me a grade. Also, I have been out of school for almost a year at this point. I am assuming he just had higher priorities to deal with, but it really makes my situation more difficult.

Comment: Actually, he may also have been dealing with illness or family issues.

Comment: That’s also possible, but he never reached out to me. Also, I basically gained nothing from the experience. Is it best to just ignore it? Or should I reach out to him again?

Comment: It will presumably be on your transcript.

Comment: Yeah it is on my transcript, which is the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I had no further information about what happened and it was me, I'd not mention it on application materials. That is, not try to explain it away. List it as a research experience on a CV, without other explanation. I'm assuming the grade you got is on a transcript. So, it isn't something you are hiding, but just not emphasizing.

If you are asked about it, you can honestly say that you don't understand the grade and that your supervisor stopped replying to your updates. You don't know why that was. Things happen. They aren't your fault. If the experience itself was valuable in setting your thinking then it was a net plus in spite of the mediocre grade. You can say those kinds of things.

But, as I mentioned in a comment, it would be good to also know why it occurred. I think I'd refrain from explaining it in written materials in any case, but you would have some additional background if the issue comes up.

Comment: I responded to the other response on this thread if you would like to check it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this happened, your professor was out of line to stop responding to emails when you were signed up for research credit, and to give you a B when this was out of your control.

On the other hand, even with this context, it does not necessarily make you look good. The issue is that people might wonder "why did this professor not want to work with this student?" and might wonder if there was some reason that you were a bad student. Of course, it would not be true, but it would unfortunately be hard to prove that you did everything you could to complete the research.

So I would do as Buffy says and not emphasize it, but have a prepared response / explanation.

Besides this, you seem to have email documentation that the professor started ignoring you, and there is a chance you could escalate this to the department chair. You should not propose that the grade be changed to an A, of course, as you did not do the work, but you could ask to have the grade removed. You could explain the situation and show the emails that were not responded to.

This would have been much more likely to work if you did it right after the grade was assigned or during the semester, so no guarantees, but it could be worth a shot. I think that overall given that you don't have any other B's, removing the B would be helpful.

Comment: So I actually emailed the prof as per Buffy’s advice. He said he was “busy with his PhD students and projects and didn’t have time to sync up”. Do you think this is the correct course of action based on that?

Comment: @masterdz522 Sorry I didn't see this at the time. But yes, I think that email is more evidence that you weren't really given a fair shot, and I would say this is the correct course of action.